# Popen not taking the arguments

Tags: python, shell, wxpython

Hi all I am learning python and shell script and for GUI i am using wxpython.

I have said to make a automated tool which does some operation , deb creation is also one of that.

for deb creation , command is:

```
              ./myfile -u username
```

I have tried os.Popen, os.system, subprocess.Popen , subprocess.call.But no use everytime "-u" wont take effect, "-u " is must. I have tried by storing "-u" in variable and the passed it but still no use.

Please suggest me the exact way or where i am doing wrong

No error message but "myfile" output shows that "-u" has not given in command.

Code is:

```
   1. cmd = ['./myfile', '-u', 'username']
      Popen(cmd,shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

   2. user = "-u" 
      name = "username"
      sbprocess.call("./myfile %s %s" %(str(user),str(name)), shell=True)
```

same kind using "os" command also

Comment: Show us the code! Your description, while eloquent, is not the same as seeing the actual code in use.

Comment: @paxdiablo: few samples i tried shown above please check.

Comment: In case 1, why `shell=True`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 'bash' instead of './'. If its bash script or else use respective. Its work only if your myfile is shell script.

```
subprocess.call("bash myfile -u %s" % str(name)), shell=True)
```

Comment: Not at all the best solution. Not flexible, uses `shell=True` where not necessary and is potentially problematic: what if `name='myself; rm -rf /'`?

Comment: @glglgl: Why ? Whats wrong i we do ? It will be helpful for me also:)

Comment: 1. What if `myfile` is not a shell script, but a binary? 2. Why invoke several levels of shell (`bash` *and* `shell=True`) 3. Why use the shell at all? What about `subprocess.call(['./myfile', '-u', name])`? (Using `check_call()` might be even better, as [proposed by J.F. Sebastian](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16997244/296974))

Answer (score 1):

The first code example in your question passes incorrect command because `shell=True` changes the meaning of the first parameter, from [the `subprocess` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> On Unix with `shell=True`, the shell defaults to `/bin/sh`. If args is a
>   string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell.
>   ..[snip]..
>
> If *args is a
>   sequence*, the first item specifies the command string, and *any
>   additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell
>   itself*. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of:

```
Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])
```

The second code example from you question should work if the following command works in a shell:

```
$ /bin/sh -c './myfile -u username'
```

---

To fix your command, you could omit possibly unnecessary `shell=True` and use [`check_call()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(["./myfile", "-u", "username"])
```